# Inner product on $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, inner-products

I have a short question. Is there some inner product on $\mathbb{Q}$?

By Inner product a I mean,  a function $\langle, \rangle:V\times V\to\mathbb{Q}$ which is linear in its first argument, positive definitess and symmetric, where $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What have you tried so far in answering this? Can you think of such a function on $\Bbb Q$? On $\Bbb Q^2$? On $\Bbb Q^3$? ... (don't try to be too clever about it!)

Comment: Depends why the ordinary dot product  is not good enough for you; still, recommend Rational Quadratic Forms by Cassels.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example, if $V=\mathbb{Q}^n$ then

$$\langle (x_1,...,x_n),(y_1,...,y_n)\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$$

is symmetric, bilinear and positive definite.

Up to a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear change of coordinates, every inner product on $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is equivalent to one of the form

$$\langle (x_1,...,x_n),(y_1,...,y_n)\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_iy_i$$
where $a_i$ are non-zero squarefree integers.